# Using metafor::rma with broom::tidy?

Tags: r, broom

I'm a complete R novice and would like to do the following:

```
library(metafor)
library(broomExtra)

df <-
  escalc(
    measure = "RR",
    ai = tpos,
    bi = tneg,
    ci = cpos,
    di = cneg,
    data = dat.bcg
  )

meta_analysis <- rma(yi, vi, data = df, method = "EB")

meta_analysis

tidy(meta_analysis)
```

Why does `tidy(meta_analysis)`always give me `NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `broomExtra::tidy_parameters` function if there is no tidier in `broom`:

```r
library(metafor)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading 'metafor' package (version 2.1-0). For an overview 

df <-
  escalc(
    measure = "RR",
    ai = tpos,
    bi = tneg,
    ci = cpos,
    di = cneg,
    data = dat.bcg
  )

meta_analysis <- rma(yi, vi, data = df, method = "EB")

broomExtra::tidy_parameters(meta_analysis)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 8
#>   term    type    estimate std.error statistic   p.value conf.low conf.high
#>   <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 overall summary   -0.715     0.181     -3.95 0.0000774    -1.07    -0.360
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked the documentation (`?tidy`). Seems there is no tidy method for an object of class `rma`. From the docs of `broomExtra::tidy`:

> Checks if a tidy method exits for a given object, either in broom or
>   in broom.mixed. If it does, it turn an object into a tidy tibble, **if
>   not, return a NULL**. In case of data frames, a tibble data frame is
>   returned.

Comment: Thanks very much -- note that my example comes from this website, which I believed to be documentation of tidy:

https://broom.tidyverse.org/reference/metafor_tidiers.html

Comment: Does this mean that the method disappeared? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's because the metafor tidiers are present only in the GitHub version of `broom` and not CRAN version.

Comment: Nice job, Indrajeet. Had the same idea. Example code works using github-version of broom as well as for your broomExtra approach.